# Insert statement with select for only one column in Informix

Tags: sql, informix

Just need to know whether this query is possible in Informix.

```
insert into emp(emp_id, sal, desg)
values (111, (select salary from emp_sal where emp_id=222), 'xxx');
```

Table structures are:

**emp**: emp_id, name, sal, desg

**emp_sal**: emp_id, sal

Comment: you should specify informix version, subqueries support was improving from version to version

Comment: i am not sure about finding version.. i did isql -v which returned "unixODBC 2.2.8 and dbaccess -V "7.31.UD6"

Comment: If you run `SELECT DBINFO('version','full') FROM informix.systables WHERE tabid = 1`, that should give you the server's full version string.  If it doesn't, your server is very old and should have been retired some time ago.  Superficially, you appear to be using IDS 7.31.UD6, which is officially out of service and has been for several years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't try with Informix but most databases support `insert into ... select`:

```
insert into emp(emp_id, sal, desg) 
select 111, salary, 'xxx' 
from emp_sal where emp_id = 222;
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement as written should work as long as the sub-query returns a single row.

Proof of Concept:

```
SQL[1871]: create temp table x(i integer, j integer, s char(10));
SQL[1872]: insert into x(i,j,s) values(1, (select atomic_number from elements where name = 'Carbon'), "Elephant");
SQL[1873]: select * from x;
1|6|Elephant
SQL[1874]:
```

My test database has a table of elements in it, hence the sub-select works for me.  Warning: I tested on 11.70.FC6, not 7.31.  Your mileage may vary given that you appear to be using a much older version of Informix (7.31 was first released before Y2K, IIRC, though 7.31.UDn was a fix-pack from the mid-2000's, probably circa 2005).